# How to send functional data to another page in React

Tags: reactjs, export, use-state

Playing.js File

```
import { useState } from "react";
function Playing(){
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const sidebarFunc = () => {
    sidebar ? setSidebar(false) : setSidebar(false);
  }

  return(
    <i onClick={sidebarFunc}>Click</i>
  );
}

export default Playing;
```

Sidebar.js File

```
function SideBar() {
  return (
    <div className="">Side Bar</div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

App.js File

```
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js";
import Playing from "./Playing.js";
function App(){
  return(
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Playing />
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm new to react, so try avoiding mistakes by my side. Here i'm trying a way in which the after clicking the `Click` text, the usestate variable `sidebar` gets triggered. But the `sidebar` couldn't be exported so as to get an outcome for `Sidebar` functional `div` as `<div className="sidebar?"Show":"Hide">Side Bar</div>`.

Is there a solution for the same or any other ways it can be done.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a state in parent component and then use this state in child component by passing through props and a callback function

App.js File

```
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js";
import Playing from "./Playing.js";
function App(){

 const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  return(
    <>
      <Sidebar sidebar={sidebar}/>
      <Playing  sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={setSidebar}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Playing.js

```
import from "react";
function Playing({sidebar,setSidebar}){


  const sidebarFunc = () => {
    sidebar ? setSidebar(false) : setSidebar(false);
  }

  return(
    <i onClick={sidebarFunc}>Click</i>
  );
}

export default Playing;
```

SideBar.js

```
   function SideBar({sidebar}) {
      return (
        <div className=`${sidebar?"Show":"Hide"}`>Side Bar</div>
      );
    }
    
export default SideBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `useState()` declaration in `App.js`.

**App.js**

```js
function App(){
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    return(
        <>
            <Sidebar sidebar={sidebar}/>
            <Playing sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={(bool) => setSidebar(bool)}/>
        </>
    );
}
```

**SideBar.js**

```js
function SideBar(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.sidebar ? "Show" : "Hide"}>Side Bar</div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

**Playing.js**

```js
function Playing(props){
    const sidebarFunc = () => {
        props.sidebar ? props.setSidebar(false) : props.setSidebar(false);
    }

    return(
        <i onClick={sidebarFunc()}>Click</i>
    );
}

export default Playing;
```